# Jenkins pipeline project trigger builds for creation of tags and branch commits

Tags: git, jenkins

I currently have a Jenkins pipeline project listen for the creation of new tags via means of Refspec

[image]

However, this does not listen for normal commits that are pushed on branches.

I have tried to use this RefSpec `+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and set the branch specifier to `**` followed by trying `**/tags/*` and `**/heads/*` but normal commits do not trigger the build. If I use two separate pipelines, I can get them working separately correctly (one only triggers for commits and the other only for new tags).

I am making use of the GitHub plugin and have `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling` enabled for the pipeline and have set up the webhook to Jenkins on GitHub. I am also using the Jenkinsfile from SCM approach.

Is it possible to have a single pipeline that can trigger builds on both new tags and normal commits?

Thanks

Comment: Update: as a workaround, we chose to go with a Freestyle job that just picks the latest commit of master and creates a tag as a part of the job. It seems like Jenkins does not handle this situation well